# Clicking Comment "Reply" Button only replies to first comment

Tags: comments, comment-form

I'm editing my comments.php, and within it I've added a reply button like this:

```
<div class="reply">
      <a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" 
        href=<?php comment_reply_link(array('reply_text' => 'Reply this comment'), comment_ID()); ?> data-commentid="3" 
          data-postid="487" data-belowelement="div-comment-3" data-respondelement="respond" 
          data-replyto="Reply to admin" aria-label="Reply to admin"> Reply
      </a>
</div>
```

When I click on the "reply" button under any comment, the comment form pops up beneath the *first* comment, and only replies to the first one, rather than the one I clicked on. Can anyone explain the errors in this code and describe how to fix it?

I also tried doing

```
<div class="reply">
  <?php comment_reply_link(); ?>
</div>
```

But the `comment_reply_link()` returns `null`, I believe.

I list the comments like so:

```
<?php
if (have_comments()) : ?>
    <ol class="post-comments">
        <?php
        wp_list_comments(array(
            'style'       => 'ol',
            'short_ping'  => true,
            'callback' => 'better_comments'
        ));
        ?>
    </ol>
    <?php
endif;
```

and have a function `better_comments() {...}` which includes the above HTML for the reply div.

Here's the first bit of that function:

```
<li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin bypostauthor even thread-even depth-1" id="comment-3" style="margin-bottom: 0.7em;">
    <div id="div-comment-3" class="comment-body">
        <div class="comment-author vcard">
            <a class="comment-author-text">
                <b><?php echo ucwords(get_comment_author()) ?></b>
            </a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you using the standard commenting APIs to list comments or have you implemented custom code to display comments? I notice you've hardcoded several parts of the HTML data attributes: `data-commentid="3" data-postid="487" data-belowelement="div-comment-3"`, and that your use of `comment_reply_link` does not match the examples in the official documentation at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_reply_link/, `comment_reply_link` does not output a URL, it outputs HTML tags

Comment: I'm using the standard commenting API's. I also tried 

`<div class="reply">
<?php comment_reply_link(array('reply_text' => 'Reply this comment'), comment_ID(), the_ID()); ?></div>` with and without the parameters for comment_reply_link. It returns null without parameters and a 4 digit number with them.

Comment: can you share more of your code so that we can see? The code you used in your questions code block is definitely broken, what you just posted in the comment replying to me is a major improvement. For the comment replying functionality to work you need the appropriate HTML IDs in place, the reply JS script, and the right functions to be used, e.g. comments are meant to be displayed using `wp_list_comments`, e.g. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/partial-and-miscellaneous-template-files/comment-template/

Comment: also `comment_reply_link` is supposed to return `null` as it does not return anything, it `echo`'s instead and is a wrapper around another function

Comment: can you include `better_comments`? My suspicion is that it is missing necessary IDs and HTML

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question to include how I go through the comments. The content of the `better_comments` function is just returning the HTML for each actual comment box (i.e the HTML for each comment is the contents of better_comments())

Comment: @NicolasGimelli, `comment_ID()` and `the_ID()` **displays/echo** the output (comment/post ID). Use `get_comment_ID()` and `get_the_ID()` instead to get the comment/post ID, e.g. to be passed as a parameter to a function.

Comment: @TomJNowell I've added the first bit of the function - I expect the error is there and not elsewhere in the function?

Comment: I realized some of the ID's were hardcoded into the divs, how do I set them to the appropriate id instead of the hardcoded "id = 'comment-3'"?

Comment: Noting that the information needed to answer this question was added when the OP re-asked the question at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/406164/comment-reply-link-reloading-page-instead-of-moving-comment-form?noredirect=1 which has now been closed as a duplicate. Do not post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment replies do not work because you're using a custom comment rendering callback function named `better_comments`, and this function hardcodes the classes IDs and other attributes rather than calling functions such as `comment_ID`.

I strongly suggest abandoning this function, and instead opting for the default commenting from a default theme. This way you can start from a known good solution, and add the functionality you want correctly and incrementally.

Additionally, lots of the things you want to add do not need a custom comment renderer, e.g. changing the reply link text can be done with filters, as can adding extra links.

You might also have forgotten to enqueue the comment reply script:

```php
    // Threaded comment reply styles.
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work for me on some buddypress pages, thanks for making me realize this. Just add  `|| is_buddypress()` to the end of the conditional. Although I think I could be more specific